# Blurry/fuzzy text in Atom on windows 10

Tags: atom-editor

I noticed that in Atom, the text is quite blurry for me. I'm running Windows 10 on a 1920x1080 resolution and Intel HD Graphics 5500. I'm using Atom 1.18.0. Can anybody help me?

[image]
Note how the text on top is much more crisp than in the text editor.

Comment: Provide a screenshot.

Comment: My bad. I updated the post with a screenshot

Comment: Is hardware acceleration enabled?

Comment: I couldn't find hardware acceleration in the atom settings - where do I find it?

Comment: Never mind, I was mistaken. Refer to [this forum post](https://discuss.atom.io/t/text-rendering-seems-blurry-compared-to-other-editors/13927/12).

Answer (score -1):

Its not the problem with  resolution , its problem with your DPI(Dots per inch) settings. As windows 10 is coming with  by default with high DPI , which make texts blurry and clipped , what you need to need to do is go to your display settings and keep the DPI at 100 % and then restart your system , it worked for me,i had same trouble with my windows application , after changing its setting , don't forget to restart your system , then only it would really take into effect

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question/answer.
Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , lesser important onces *Italic*
Also use lists if necessary